# Complex string compare logic

Tags: c#, .net

I need help with some complex (for me anyway as I not too experienced) string comparison logic. Basically, I want to validate a string to make sure it matches a format rule. I am using C#, targeting .NET 4.5.2.

I am trying to work with an API which gives me the expected format of the string this way:

> 1:420+4:9####  (must have “420” starting in position 1  AND have a “9” in position 4 AND have numeric digits in positions 5-8
>
> 2:Z+14:&&+20:10,11,12  (must have a “Z” in position 2 AND and alpha letters in positions 14, 15  AND have either “10”, “11”, or “12” starting in position 20
>
> Legend:
>
> ":" =  position/valuelist separator
>
> "," =  value separator
>
> "+" =  test separator
>
> "#" =  numeric digit-only wildcard
>
> "&" =  alpha letter-only wildcard

Given this, my first thought is to do a series of substrings and splits of the input string and then do compare on each section? Or, I could do a for loop and iterate through each character one by one until I hit the end of the length of the input string.

Let's assume in this case that the input string is something like "420987435744585". Using rule number one, I should get a pass on this since the first three are 420, position 4 is a 9 and the next 5-8 are numeric.

So far, I have created a method that returns a bool if I pass/fail validation. The input string is passed in. I then started to split on + or - to get all of the and or not sections and then split on comma to get the groups of rules. But this is where I am stuck. It seems like it should be easy and maybe it is but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it and I am thinking I am going to end up with a ton of arrays, foreach loops, if statements, etc... Just to validate and return true/false if the input string matches my format.

Can somebody please assist and give some guidance?

Thank you!!!!

Comment: can you use regular expressions?

Comment: Yes, I can use regex. I see the response below along these lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is a custom function, it will be faster than RegEx, and it would be a lot of manual work to convert that format to RegEx.

I've made a start at the validation function, and it's testing ok for the samples you provided.

Here is the code:

```
static bool CheckFormat(string formatString, string value)
{
    string[] tests = formatString.Split('+');

    foreach(string test in tests)
    {
        string[] testElement = test.Split(':');
        int startPos = int.Parse(testElement[0]);
        string patterns = testElement[1];

        string[] patternElements = patterns.Split(',');

        foreach(string patternElement in patternElements)
        {

            //value string not long enough, so fail.
            if(startPos + patternElement.Length > value.Length)
                return false;

            for (int i = 0; i < patternElement.Length; i++)
            {
                switch(patternElement[i])
                {
                    case '#':
                        if (!Char.IsNumber(value[i]))
                            return false;
                        break;

                    case '&':

                        if (!Char.IsLetter(value[i]))
                            return false;
                        break;

                    default:

                        if(patternElement[i] != value[i])
                            return false;
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The dotnet fiddle is here if you want to play with it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/52olLQ.

Good luck.

Comment: Gary, thank you for the feedback and for the code sample. I very much appreciate it as it helps me understand to also see it. I will play around with this tomorrow and update this thread with my results so others may benefit from my experiments.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle these conditions would be using Regular Expressions (Regex). At first, you may find it a bit complicated, but it's worth to put time on learning it to handle all types of string patterns in a simple non-verbose way.

You can start with these tutorials :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_regular_expressions.htm

And use this one as a reference :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply. I am starting to see a lot on Regex so I think it is time I learn it so thank you also for the links and the reading material. I am going to educate myself using these tutorials so that I have this as an option.